# Vis Timeline - I don't want to change item.start and move. But i need to change item.end?

Tags: vis.js, vis-timeline

I have one item. And item is fixed for item.start, and item shall not be moved. I need to change just item.end.

I was trying something. For example if item.class name is record-scheduled, item.start should be in the future. This code worked. But I couldn't build for start is constant.

```
  onMoving: function (item, callback) {

    if(item.className == 'record-scheduled'){
      var min = moment()
      var max = moment(item.start).add(6,'hours')
      if (item.start < min) item.start = min;
      if (item.start > max) item.start = max;
      if (item.end   > max) item.end   = max;
      callback(item); // send back the (possibly) changed item
    }else if(item.className == 'record-finished'){
      callback(null)
    }else if(item.className =='record-active'){
      callback(item)
    }
    else{
      callback(item)

    }
    


  },
```

My timeline options:

```
options: {
    editable: true,
    stack: false,
    start:moment().format(), 
}
```

**explain is briefly:**

```
else if(item.className =='record-active'){

item.start = 'cannot be changed'
item.end = 'can be change'
item.draggable = 'cannot be draggable'
}
```

How could i solve it?

Thanks, Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a new solution while opening the thread. Maybe It's not best way but the way worked for me. But you have to database. I didn't find how to get beforeItemStart other way. Maybe somebody help us for this. And my my solution is like;

```
    else if(item.className =='record-active'){

      axios
      .get('http://localhost:3000/' + item.id)
      .then(response => (this.selectedItem = response.data))
      var findstarttime = new Long(this.selectedItem.StartDateTime.Ticks.low, 
      this.selectedItem.StartDateTime.Ticks.high,false).toNumber();
      var oneZeroGoneFindStartTime = findstarttime / 10000
      var findedstarttime = moment(oneZeroGoneFindStartTime)
      console.log(findedstarttime)



      var beforeItemStart = findedstarttime
      if(beforeItemStart < item.start) item.start = beforeItemStart;
      if(beforeItemStart > item.start) item.start = beforeItemStart;
      callback(item)

      
    }
```

I find beforeItemStart and It's always item.start = beforeItemStart.
And It can't draggable, just I can change end range. But here an axios causes too many queries. I need to fix that. Maybe it will be a solution for someone until a better answer comes.

Thanks, Regards.